# Makefile for Debian - function calls in main

Tags: c++, function, makefile, debian

so I have this structure:

simpleConnect.cpp (contains main)
      Call feature_extract.cpp

feature_extract.cpp (does some things here, returns to simpleConnect)

ThesisHeader.h (has declaration of feature_extract and all the includes etc...)

Now...These files use a library called ARIA (used for mobilerobots) and a set of header files - EIGEN (for matrix manipulations etc)

I used to suggested structure by Aria as follows:

```
SOURCES=simpleConnect
all: $(SOURCES)

CFLAGS=-fPIC -g -Wall
ARIA_INCLUDE =-I/usr/local/Aria/include
ARIA_LINK=-L/usr/local/Aria/lib -lAria -lpthread -ldl -lrt


%: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(ARIA_INCLUDE) $< -o $@ $(ARIA_LINK)
```

But I'm getting this error at the line where I call the function feature_extract:

undefined reference to 'feature_extract(......)'
collect2: ld reurned 1 exit status

As far as I can understand this is to do with me not telling the compiler that feature_extract is there....because I don't know how...

I tried adding pieces I found online but to no avail, hence I came asking here.

Could anyone be kind enough to modify the makefile so as to include that file to be able to compile?

Thank you for your time,
Patrick

Comment: `ld` is the linker, not the compiler.

Comment: `SOURCES` should be `SOURCES=simpleConnect.cpp feature_extract.cpp`

Comment: If I try: SOURCES=simpleConnect.cpp feature_extract.cpp

I get error "No rule to make target 'feature_extract.cpp', needed by 'all'. Stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, thanks to those who helped.

I ended up reading the GNU make manual, which solved my problem.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf

This is the final makefile that ended up working:

```
    CFLAGS=-fPIC -g -Wall
ARIA_INCLUDE =-I/usr/local/Aria/include
ARIA_LINK=-L/usr/local/Aria/lib -lAria -lpthread -ldl -lrt

edit : simpleConnect.o feature_extract.o
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(ARIA_INCLUDE) -o edit simpleConnect.o
feature_extract.o $(ARIA_LINK)

simpleConnect.o : simpleConnect.cpp ThesisHeader.h feature_extract.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(ARIA_INCLUDE) -c simpleConnect.cpp $(ARIA_LINK)

feature_extract.o : feature_extract.cpp ThesisHeader.h
        $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(ARIA_INCLUDE) -c feature_extract.cpp $(ARIA_LINK)

clean :
        rm edit simpleConnect.o feature_extract.o
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This app needs `feature_extract`.

   You're using "SOURCES" for something other than sources.

```
CFLAGS=-fPIC -g -Wall
ARIA_INCLUDE =-I/usr/local/Aria/include
ARIA_LINK=-L/usr/local/Aria/lib -lAria -lpthread -ldl -lrt

app_name: simpleConnect.cpp feature_extract.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(ARIA_INCLUDE) $^ -o $@ $(ARIA_LINK)
```

If this works, further refinements are possible.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply but unfortunately this didn't work either, returned the same error as before.  Do I maybe need to add the header (ThesisHeader.h) somewhere in there?  Please forgive me but I have no knowledge on how to do this and I'm trying to just use the file to compile, ie its just a technicality to get the code working!  Thanks again

Comment: @user2220824: could you elaborate?

Comment: I solved the problem, and posted an answer to my own question, thank your for the help.